# How install postgis_raster extention on PostgreSQL 11.5?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster

I want install postgis_raster extension on PostreSQL 11.5 + PostGIS 2.5.3 + MacOS 10.14.6

There is a install script on https://postgis.net/install/.

All installations of extensions work fine, except postgis_raster:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
2019-11-12 17:39:19.416 CET [88243] ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/postgis_raster.control": No such file or directory
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PostGIS excluded the raster types and functions from the main extension **as of version 3.x**; a separate `CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;` is then necessary to get raster support.

**Versions 2.x have full raster support as part of the main extension environment**, so `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` is all you need.